# Spatialite not loaded in PHP5 on Ubuntu

Tags: spatialite, php, sqlite, apache

I'm trying to install Spatialite (4.3.0a) on Ubuntu (14.94.2 LTS) ..... I'd like to use it with PHP (5.5.9-1) ....

Following this post

https://faimsproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/FAIMS/Installing+Spatialite+4+on+Ubuntu

(obviously using the updated versions of the packages involved....), I've now installed:

- PHP 5.5.9-1
- SQLite 3.9.2
- Proj4 4.9.2
- Geos 3.5.0
- Freexl 1.0.2
- Spatialite 4.3.0a

I've also exported /usr/local/lib

```
export "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib"
```

It seems that SQLITE 3 and Spatialite are working fine ...

```
sqlite3 myDB
SQLite version 3.9.2 2015-11-02 18:31:45
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');

sqlite> SELECT sqlite_version();
3.9.2
sqlite> SELECT spatialite_version();
4.3.0a
sqlite> SELECT proj4_version();
Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015
sqlite> SELECT geos_version();
3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4084
sqlite> .quit
```

But if I try to execute this simple PHP file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing SpatiaLite on PHP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>testing SpatiaLite on PHP</h1>

<?php
# connecting some SQLite DB
# we'll actually use an IN-MEMORY DB
# so to avoid any further complexity;
# an IN-MEMORY DB simply is a temp-DB 
$db = new SQLite3(':memory:');

# loading SpatiaLite as an extension
$db->loadExtension('/usr/local/lib/mod_spatialite.so');


# enabling Spatial Metadata
# using v.2.4.0 this automatically initializes SPATIAL_REF_SYS
# and GEOMETRY_COLUMNS
$db->exec("SELECT InitSpatialMetadata()");

# reporting some version info
$rs = $db->query('SELECT sqlite_version()');
while ($row = $rs->fetchArray())
{
  print "<h3>SQLite version: $row[0]</h3>";
}
$rs = $db->query('SELECT spatialite_version()');
while ($row = $rs->fetchArray())
{
  print "<h3>SpatiaLite version: $row[0]</h3>";
}

?>

  </body>
</html>
```

... the result is

```
testing SpatiaLite on PHP

SQLite version: 3.9.2
```

so it seems that somthing is going wrong with loading Spatialite.

My php.ini configuration is the follow

```
[sqlite]
 http://php.net/sqlite.assoc-case
sqlite.assoc_case = 0

[sqlite3]
sqlite3.extension_dir = /var/www/html/test/sqlite3_ext
```

In /var/www/html/test/sqlite3_ext there are

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cesare cesare 15527574 Dec  1 22:17 libspatialite.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cesare cesare 15944537 Dec  2 22:28 mod_spatialite.so
```

Comment: The spatialite.so should be in the sqlite extension directory, isn't it? On the following site you can find more info: http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0-4/splite-php.html

Comment: Yes Zoltan, I've followed those instructions ( there is an updated version now here ....http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/php.html),  and all the .so libraries are in sqlite extension directory ... but it stiil doesn't work

Comment: But you load mod_spatialite from other dir: `$db->loadExtension('/usr/local/lib/mod_spatialite.so');` Does this statement return TRUE?

Comment: I've tried to modify my code using $db->loadExtension('/var/www/html/test/sqlite3_ext/mod_spatialite.so'); but no news ...... When I try to execute the code from command line ... php Mytest.php ... the error is PHP Warning:  SQLite3::loadExtension(): SQLite Extension are disabled in /var/www/html/test/MyTest.php

Answer (score 2):

I've solved putting

```
$db->loadExtension('mod_spatialite.so');
```

in my PHP code and configuring the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable in this way

```
export "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib"
```

for execution from command line